# Unsure why code doesn't work C++ simple

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

trying to prevent the user from entering a char. This code makes sense in my head. The first if statement that i made works as intended (It prevents the user from entering a char). But when the user makes a correct choice, the switch goes straight to the default case. the switch was working perfectly before i entered the error handling if statement. cheers for the help

```
void Input()
{
char errorhandle;
int a;
cout << "It's " << player << "'s turn Enter where you want your shape: ";
cin >> errorhandle;

if (errorhandle < '0' || errorhandle > '9')
{
    cout << "You have not entered a number try again!" << endl;
    Input();
}
else
{
    a = (int)errorhandle;
}

switch (a)
{
case 1:
    if (board[0][0] == '1')
    {
        board[0][0] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The place is already in use, try again!" << endl;
        Input();
    };
    break;

case 2:
    if (board[0][1] == '2')
    {
        board[0][1] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The place is already in use, try again!" << endl;
        Input();
    };
    break;

case 3:
    if (board[0][2] == '3')
    {
        board[0][2] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The place is already in use, try again!" << endl;
        Input();
    };
    break;

case 4:
    if (board[1][0] == '4')
    {
        board[1][0] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The place is already in use, try again!" << endl;
        Input();
    };
    break;

case 5:
    if (board[1][1] == '5')
    {
        board[1][1] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The place is already in use, try again!" << endl;
        Input();
    };
    break;

case 6:
    if (board[1][2] == '6')
    {
        board[1][2] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The place is already in use, try again!" << endl;
        Input();
    };
    break;

case 7:
    if (board[2][0] == '7')
    {
        board[2][0] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The place is already in use, try again!" << endl;
        Input();
    };
    break;

case 8:
    if (board[2][1] == '8')
    {
        board[2][1] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The place is already in use, try again!" << endl;
        Input();
    };
    break;

case 9:
    if (board[2][2] == '9')
    {
        board[2][2] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The place is already in use, try again!" << endl;
        Input();
    };
    break;

default:
    cout << "You have entered an invalid option, try again" << endl;
    Input();
}
```

}

Comment: An error message/explanation of what is happening would help.

Comment: You obviously have to refactor your code to avoid repetitions. Also, provide error text from compiler.

Comment: You probably mean != instead of == immediately after each case statement

Comment: By the way, with a little math you can remove the `switch` statement.  The `row = number / 3;` the `column = number % 3;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you've identified the error,  you call your function again:

```
Input();
```

When the user then enters a good number,  it executes the switch with the good input.  Then it returns to the caller, resuming after the error processing, and executes a second time the switch with an uninitialised `a`

There is another issue:  when you convert the input into an integer using  `a = (int)errorhandle;`,  an input of '1' will be converted into the ascii value of '1'  and not into 1.  So your case values should rather stick to the quoted values.

**Potential correction:**

```
while ( (cin >> errorhandle) && (errorhandle < '0' || errorhandle > '9') )
    cout << "You have not entered a number try again! " << endl;
a = errorhandle-'0';
switch (a)
...
```

Comment: Your correction fixed my problem, thank you. I would like to thank everyone else who helped also. I'll have to read up on ascii values. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
a = (int)errorhandle;
```

you are converting an ascii `char` to an `int`. The value of '1' is not the same as 1. Look at the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Also after your recursive call to `Input()` you will go on to use `a` in a `switch` statement uninitialized.

```
if (errorhandle < '0' || errorhandle > '9') {
    cout << "You have not entered a number try again!" << endl;
    Input();
    return; // Stop execution after this line. 
            // This should be done in all cases of a call to input. 
} else {
    a = (int)(errorhandle - '0');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers exaplain what is happeneing you can fix it like this:

```
if (errorhandle < '0' || errorhandle > '9')
{
    cout << "You have not entered a number try again!" << endl;
    Input();
    return; // < new | stops the function
}
```

I would avoid recursion in this case but this works too.

and you can't convert a char to an int like that. Don't even convert to an int just compare the char values in the switch statement.